# Inner class object as Outer class constructor argument

Tags: java, class, interface

I have an abstract wrapping class Foo which get functionality defined by providing it with the Interface Reader. All works well when I'm implementing a seperate Reader and provide it.
It goes wrong when I'm, trying to do this via a inner class. Having the Reader implementation in an inner class is a requirement for me.

```
public abstract class Foo
    {
        private Reader reader;

        public Foo(Reader reader)
        {
            this.reader = reader;
        }

        public void read()
        {
            this.reader.doit();
        }
    }
```

"No enclosing instance of type MapLink is available due to some intermediate constructor invocation"

```
public class ReaderFoo extends Foo
{
    public class FooReader implements Reader
    {
        @Override
        public void doit()
        {
            // functionality
        }
    }   

    public ReaderFoo ()
    {
        super(new FooReader());
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try making `FooReader` `static`. Inner classes in Java are bound to an *instance* of the outer rather than the *class* unless they're *static*.

```
public class ReaderFoo extends Foo
{
    public static class FooReader implements Reader
    {
        @Override
        public void doit()
        {
            // functionality
        }
    }   

    public ReaderFoo ()
    {
        super(new FooReader());
    }
}
```

You cannot use an instance inner class before actually having an instance, as the actual type of the `Reader` is going to be like `myInstance.Reader`.

Comment: You are generally right, but I wonder why I can't even do it with super(new MapLink.MapReader()); What's the Point of the public keyword then?

Comment: `new MapLink.MapReader()` is implicitly turned into new `MapLink.MapReader(MapLink.this)` by the compiler (if `MapReader` is an inner class), and `MapLink.this` is not available yet.

Comment: @JamieFlowers Could you show us some code of `MapLink` and `MapReader`?

Comment: Sorry, wrong copy paste. I meant super(new ReaderFoo.FooReader());

Comment: Do you know where I can read more about this implicit conversion? It's not very intuitive with the new keyword normally marking a new object creation.

Comment: But nevertheless thank you very much for the answer, both of you. It makes more sense to have the Reader static anyway.

Comment: @JamieFlowers The correct code would be `super(new ReaderFoo().new FooReader());` for a non-static nested class. *Correct* means *compiles without* error here, I'd rather recommend you to use a static class.

Comment: @JamieFlowers: see for example Jon Skeet's answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728842/instantiating-an-inner-class. I can't find the appropriate section in the JLS, but I can hunt for it if it helps.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that the constructor to `FooReader` requires the outer class (`ReaderFoo`) to be instantiated before it (because inner classes store a reference to their containing instance), but you're making one in the *constructor* to `ReaderFoo`. It's a chicken-and-egg problem.